# Laravel problema con los path de la app en entornos UNIX vs WINDOWS

Tags: laravel

tengo un problemilla con los path de mi app. Trata de lo siguiente; yo tengo esta funcion :

```
public static function getUtilsDir($path = '')
{
    $path = app_path("Utils\\$path");
    return $path;
}
//$path =self::getUtilsDir('Types');
// WIN - Output = "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelApp\app\Utils\Types"
// LINUX - Output = "/home/vagrant/code/app/Utils\Types"
```

Como se puede apreciar, segun el SO muestra para un lado el slash , se adapta segun el SO, pero cuando pongo los slash hijos yo manualmente no y hace lo que quiere, como podria hacer para que segun el SO pongan sus respectivos slash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo usando la constante [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dir.constants.php) que asigna automaticamente `/ or \` dependiendo del tipo de so.

puedes ayudarte de los metodos de laravel para obtene los path absolutos.

```
public_path(); // Path of public/
base_path(); // Path of application root
storage_path(); // Path of storage/
app_path(); // Path of app/
```

## ejemplo directo de la web oficial

```
function file_build_path(...$segments) {
    return join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $segments);
}
file_build_path("home", "alice", "Documents", "example.txt")
// app_path() laravel
file_build_path(app_path("Utils\\$path"), "alice", "Documents", "example.txt");
```